# how to get notification from another server in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am getting data from the server, and I want to show a push notification in android.  How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific and does not contain enough information: What did you do to approach this problem? Have you considered other sources? What is your concrete programming question? Please see the FAQ or http://tinyurl.com/so-hints/ to learn how to ask good questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be clear to yourself What do you exactly want, I think you are using just a web service to get data. For push Notifiaction you need to implement [Android Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) and [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) you can find complete tutorial.

Cheers